# How to Insert Shape at cursor position in MSWORD using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to insert a shape in Word above the picture where ever user clicks.

I have written the program below, but sometimes it is placing the rectangle incorrectly and inserting it twice: once where I need it and again somewhere else.

Why is the Shape being inserted twice?

```
Private WithEvents app As Word.Application

Private Sub app_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
Cancel = True
Call CurosrXY_Pixels
End SuB

Sub CurosrXY_Pixels()
ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, fcnXCoord, fcnYCoord, 20#, 16#).Select
With Selection
.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Select
.Collapse
.Font.Name = "Arial"
.Font.Size = 7
.Font.Bold = False
.Paragraphs.FirstLineIndent = 0
.Paragraphs.RightIndent = -10
.Paragraphs.LeftIndent = -10
.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
.TypeText Text:=11
.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoCTrue
End With
End Sub

Function fcnXCoord() As Double
fcnXCoord = Selection.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
End Function

Function fcnYCoord() As Double
fcnYCoord = Selection.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
End Function
```

Comment: Note that only one issue is allowed per question, according to the site guidelines (see the [help]). I've chosen the issue about the code executing twice, in my edit, as solving that in the way I describe in my answer may also help with the other issue. If the placement issue remains unresolved, please post that in a *new* question with more information about *how* the positioning is incorrect: describe what you expect and how the result differs.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the code is firing more than once is because of the use of the `Select` method. Code changing the selection is the same as the user doing so. The way to avoid this is to work directly with the Word objects.

The code below illustrates this in the procedure `CurosrXY_Pixels`. A `Shape` object is declared, then the newly inserted drawing object assigned to it. This then used for setting the formatting and text, in the `With` block.

Notice I've also passed the `Selection` object from the event to this procedure, as well as to the two that calculate the co-ordinates. Since, conceivably, the user could click again before the macro finishes, it's important to pass along the original `Selection`. (That the original code was not doing so probably contributed to the "randomness" of where things were being created since the code, itself, was changing the selection.)

The code line in the `app_WindowSelectionChange` event to call the other procedures: `CurosrXY_Pixels Sel`

```
Sub CurosrXY_Pixels(Sel As Word.Selection)
    Dim shp As Word.Shape

    Set shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, fcnXCoord(Sel), fcnYCoord(Sel), 20#, 16#, Sel.Range)
    With shp.TextFrame.TextRange
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.Size = 7
        .Font.Bold = False
        .Paragraphs.FirstLineIndent = 0
        .Paragraphs.RightIndent = -10
        .Paragraphs.LeftIndent = -10
        .Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        .Text = 11
    End With
    shp.LockAspectRatio = msoCTrue
End Sub

Function fcnXCoord(Sel As Word.Selection) As Double
    fcnXCoord = Sel.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
End Function

Function fcnYCoord(Sel As Word.Selection) As Double
    fcnYCoord = Sel.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
End Function
```

Comment: you are right but I had tried though when I clicked the left click first time it insert shape in wrong side when I again click in creates at the cursor position that result in two side creation.

Can u help to solve this.

Comment: @ateeqofficeuse Your comment is not clear. This answer addresses why the code was executing multiple times. If that issue is solved, this should be designated as the answer (click the check mark next to it). Then ask a *new* question for a different problem (location, apparently). Make sure to explain the issue very thoroughly and clearly, including the code to reproduce it. Please note that Stack Overflow is not a "forum" - we do not carry on a discussion until each and every question you have is answered: for each problem a new question is required. You may want to visit the [help].